# Atualizando dados de uma div?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Como faço para atualizar as informações de um elemento `div` com jQuery sem necessariamente recarregar a página?

Ex.: Enviar um `post` de um `insert` e as informações desse `insert` aparecerem logo na `div` puxando do banco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a função `$.post` da JQuery:

```
$("#form").submit(function() { // QUANDO ENVIAR O FORM
    var login = $("#login").val(); // VALOR DO LOGIN
    var senha = $("#senha").val(); // VALOR DO INPUT SENHA
        $.post('logar.php', { // FUNÇÃO POST, LOGAR.PHP FAZ A INSERÇÃO NO MYSQL             
            login: login,
            senha: senha
        }, function(resposta) {
            $("#divresposta").html(resposta); // RESPOSTA
        }, 'html');
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Está dando um erro na linha:                    $("#form").submit(function() { // QUANDO ENVIAR O FORM
    var login = $("#login").val(); // VALOR DO LOGIN
    var senha = $("#senha").val(); // VALOR DO INPUT SENHA
        $.post('logar.php', { // FUNÇÃO POST, LOGAR.PHP FAZ A INSERÇÃO NO MYSQL             
            login: login,
            senha: senha
        }, function(resposta) {
            $("#divresposta").html(resposta); // RESPOSTA
            }
        }, 'html');   //<<<<<<<<<<< ERRO AQUI
        return false;
});

Comment: corrigi!!!obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2):

Estude basicamente a função `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Fonte: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Você pode fazer o seguinte (não testei, porém é basicamente isto):

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "insert_func.php",
    type: "post",
    data: { name: "bruce", age: 23 }, // dados que serão processados
    success: function(response) {
        $(".your-div-class").html(response);
    }
});
```